# MySQL How to get a sum of items

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having huge problems with writing a proper query to solve my problem. So quick description of my problem:

A is a set made of products B and C., For example, set A is made of 4xB and 1xC.le set A is made of 4xB and 1xC.

```
Set A
4x B
1x C
```

I can also separately sell product B or C.

So if I sell one set A and one product B, I should get a result like

```
Product:   Sold:
A          1
B          5
C          1
```

Data structure:

```
table products
id  name
1   A
2   B
3   C

table products_subset
id    parent_id    product_id    amount
1     1            2             4
2     1            3             1

table documents
doc_id   type    code
1        bill    INV-1
2        bill    INV-2

table document_products
id   doc_id   prod_id   amount    price
1    1        1         1         10
2    2        2         1         2
```

If this can't be solved by the query, then I'll just write a code to do the math but would like to do as much as possible in the query itself.

Comment: Please show your table structure.

Comment: we can't really tell you anything unless we can see the data structure, all we've got is an abstract description and a desired output. Also have you got any queries you tried already as a starting point?

Comment: I have updated my post with simplified data structure.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    product_id, `name`, SUM(amount)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        dp.product_id, p.`name`, dp.amount
    FROM
        document_products dp
    JOIN products p ON p.id = dp.product_id 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        ps.product_id, p1.`name`, ps.amount
    FROM
        document_products dp
    JOIN products p ON p.id = dp.product_id
    JOIN products_subset ps ON dp.product_id = ps.parent_id
    JOIN products p1 ON p1.id = ps.product_id) AS t1
GROUP BY 1 , 2
```

Result

```
id  name    amount
1   A       1
2   B       5
3   C       1
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to put together query which returns right amount. My whole query:

```
select warehouse_id, sum(amount_reserved), sum(amount_shipped) from (
select
    doc.warehouse_id warehouse_id,
    sum(puso.so_amount) amount_reserved,
    sum(puso.so_amount_shipped) amount_shipped
from
    products_use pu
    left join products_use_documents puso on (puso.company_id = 1111 and 
puso.products_use_id = pu.id)
    left join documents doc on (doc.id = puso.parent_id and doc.company_id = 1111)
where
    pu.company_id = 1111
    and pu.a_id = 11112222333
    and pu.parent_type = 'PR_SO'
    and doc.status_closed_manually = 0
    and doc.status_shipped = 0
    and doc.warehouse_id is not null
    and IF(puso.so_amount is not null, puso.so_amount, 0) > IF(puso.so_amount_shipped is not null, puso.so_amount_shipped, 0)
UNION
select
    doc.warehouse_id warehouse_id,
    sum(puso.so_amount * ps.amount) amount_reserved,
    sum(puso.so_amount_shipped * ps.amount) amount_shipped
from
    product_sets ps
    left join products_use pu on (ps.product_id = pu.a_id)
    left join products_use_documents puso on (puso.company_id = 1111 and puso.products_use_id = au.id)
    left join documents doc on (doc.id = puso.parent_id and doc.company_id = 1111)
where
    ps.company_id = 1111 and
    ps.product_set_id = 11112222333 and
    pu.company_id = 1111
    and pu.parent_type = 'PR_SO'
    and doc.status_closed_manually = 0
    and doc.status_shipped = 0
    and doc.warehouse_id is not null
    and IF(puso.so_amount is not null, puso.so_amount, 0) > IF(puso.so_amount_shipped is not null, puso.so_amount_shipped, 0)) l
group by l.warehouse_id
```